Fish Tank For Merfolk
I haven't seen any questions like these, but please do tell me if it is a duplicate. What I need to know is:
How large would a tank need to be for a merperson -maximum length around 9 feet long from head to tail fin- to fit in comfortably for the purposes of sleeping and general hanging out.
TL;DR
How large should a tank be for a merperson to be able to comfortably hang out in?
Edit: The merperson in question will do most if not all their sleeping there.(I imagine they sleep like a fish, or wrapped in kelp like an otter) Exercise, eating and socializing will mostly occur elsewhere, although at least some will happen while in the tank. The tank doesn't necessarily need to be large enough to hold multiple merfolk, although if it is, that's a good bonus.
As the OP, I have received answers necessary to my worldbuilding process and will not be trying to re-open this question. However, in the future, I would appreciate it if people would refrain from voting to close questions as "opinion-based" without giving reasons as to why they are doing so.

Doesn't that slightly depend on the needs of the merpeep in question? How do they sleep? Do they do all their eating and exercising and socializing elsewhere? Is this just for a few sleep sessions, or does it need to be a permanent home? 9ft long seems pretty hefty.

Good point! I will edit the question to be more clear.

Is this a "fish tank" for a merperson out of their normal habitat? Sort of like an out-of-sea hotel room? Given the very broad range of size between a micro hotel space in Tokyo (something like 16 sqft) versus a palatial presidential suite that might exceed a thousand sqft, I'd say that the question becomes highly opinion based and / or story based. I'm voting to close on that basis.

Ok. Do that if you like. It is for a merperson out of their normal habitat, if by "normal habitat" you mean outside of a large body of water preferably connected to the sea. If you read the entire question, you would see that I ask only how large it would need to be for the purposes of sleeping and perhaps hanging out with a few friends. If you think it's opinion based, then that is your OPINION, so go right ahead. People have answered it in a way that is satifactory to myself, so I don't mind.

Is the tank closed or open?

Open. It's less of a cell for keeping the character trapped and more of like a bedroom for them to sleep in, store their belongings, etc.

Probably around 10-12 feet in diameter. Justification: if you’re 6 feet tall, how long is your bed? Probably a few feet longer than you are, if you’re sleeping in a comfortable bed. Same logic applies here.
As for amenities, that’s all blankets and pillows for us. Only if you have a lot of pillows does the number of pillows you have factor into the size of the bed you get. Any amenities like kelp a merperson would have is equivalent to their “pillow”, so same logic applies.
As for how they might sleep, I would suggest something otter-like. Fish sleep in a way justified by their size and physiology, as do otters; your merfolk are going to be physiologically more “otter” than “fish” on account of their size and arms.
If you want merfolk to be able to hang out, make it a full-size room many more feet in diameter. Your whole room isn’t encompassed by your bed, is it?
